# What is the return type of lambda function in python?

Tags: python, lambda, return-type

When you create a lambda in Python, what type is returned? E.g. `type(lambda x: x+1)` returns

Comment: It returns whatever your own code to test it returns? What is stopping you from running that?

Comment: The type of `x + 1`

Comment: `name = lambda <params>: <whatever>` is the same as `def name(<params>): return <whatever>`

Comment: You can think of lambda is like a shorthand function. For example `lambda x: x+1` is like `def my_function(x): return x + 1` So, the type of your lambda is the type of x + 1

Comment: `f = lambda x: x+1; print type(f)`
returns `<type 'function'>`

Comment: As with other callable objects, the type returned by a lambda function is a Python object (`PyObject`).

Comment: @cdarke well sure *everything* is an `object` in Python, but specifically lambda expressions evaluate to function objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I misunderstood the question.   I read it as what  type could a lambda function *return*, not what class a lambda function belongs to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lambda is almost as same as defining a regular function.

In your case, it is equivalent to:

```
def _(x):
    return x+1
```

Because of that, and because the dynamic typing nature of Python, the type of the return value depends on what the function does.

Calling the function with different values can return different values:

```
In [2]: y = lambda x: x+1

In [3]: y(1)
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: type(y(1))
Out[4]: int

In [5]: y(1.0)
Out[5]: 2.0

In [6]: type(y(1.0))
Out[6]: float
```

---

When asking about the type of **the lambda function itself**, the type is just `function`:

```
In [1]: type(lambda x: x+1)
Out[1]: function
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> type(lambda x: x+1)
<class 'function'>
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the same type that you might expect. If you set:

```
y = lambda x: x+1
```

then `type(y(1))` will return `int` `type(y(1.1))` will return `float`. `type(y)` will simply return `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are just simple syntactic sugar on top of functions. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (emphasis mine):

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the lambda keyword. This function returns the sum of its two arguments: lambda a, b: a+b. Lambda functions can be used wherever function objects are required. They are syntactically restricted to a single expression. **Semantically, they are just syntactic sugar for a normal function definition.** Like nested function definitions, lambda functions can reference variables from the containing scope: